# MANIFEST.in is not adding data folder inside site-packages

Tags: python, manifest, setuptools, python-packaging

Following is the structure of folder

```
project_name
    src
        pkg
            folder1
                __init__.py
                mod1
            folder2
                __init__.py
                mod1
                data_folder
                    data.pkl
            __init__.py
    __init__.py
    MANIFEST.in
    setup.py
```

To make sure that data_folder is included in the package, I wrote MANIFEST.in

```
include src/pkg/folder2/data_folder/*
```

and for setup.py

```
package_dir={"": "src"},
packages=find_packages("src"),
include_package_data=True,
```

However, when I checked site-packages, there was no `data_folder`. What did I miss?

Comment: Have you tired adding a (empty) `__init__.py` module in `src/pkg/folder2/data_folder`?

Comment: @sinoroc The folder is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `setuptools` is used, manifest file is not longer required. Setuptools takes care of it.

Instead, this has to be done in `setup.py` file.

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
.
.
package_data={"pkg":["folder2/data_folder/*.pkl"]},
include_package_data=True,
.
.
)
```

Also, `__init__.py` are not required inside `data_folder` and its sub-folders. This has solved the problem for me.